# How do I select the li element from dropdown using java in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium3

[image]

Below are the code which I used:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=' flag-dropdown']")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']/li"));
    By Country1 = By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']/li[85]");
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(Country1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    for (WebElement opt : options) {
        if (opt.equals(element1)) {
            WebElement element3 = null;
            element3 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(Country1));
            element3.click();   
        }
    }
```

My error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <li data-flag-key="flag_no_83" class="country" data-dial-code="1" tabindex="0" data-country-code="is" role="option">...</li> is not clickable at point (746, 276). Other element would receive the click: <input class="search-box" type="search" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off" value="">
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

and it scrolls to the required country but I'm unable to click it.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and point to the places where it does not work.

Comment: Please add this to the original question. Format the code. What error are you getting?

Comment: @pavelsaman I formatted the code, but couldn't find any error when I run my script and it failed to select the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for you, but your error say that some other element hide the element you want to click on.
Try this :

```
element3 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Country1));
```

instead of

```
element3 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(Country1));
```

Many time some element hide yours, some times you should try by javascript solution

```
JavaScriptExecutor jsExec = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jsExec.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(country1));   
jsExec.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(country1))
```

Hope this can help